# Laravel - Confide - Save Change Password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, change-password

I managed to save a new password or change a password for a logged in user.

```
    public function saveNewPassword() {
    $rules = array(
        'old_password'            => 'required',
        'password'       => 'required|confirmed|different:old_password',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|different:old_password|same:password_confirmation'
    );
    $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
    // Validate the inputs
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);


    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    } else {
        $password = Input::get( 'password' );
        $passwordConfirmation = Input::get( 'password_confirmation' );

        if(!empty($password)) {
            if($password === $passwordConfirmation) {
                $user->password = $password;
                $user->password_confirmation = $passwordConfirmation;
            } 
        } else {
            unset($user->password);
            unset($user->password_confirmation);
        }

        // Save if valid. Password field will be hashed before save
        $user->save();
    }

    // Get validation errors (see Ardent package)
    $error = $user->errors()->all();

    if(empty($error)) {
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully saved!');
        return Redirect::back();

    } else {
        Session::flash('error', $error);
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

The problem I have is, how to check the Old Password, that is equal to the current password? Any Ideas? Does Confide has his own methods for changing passwords?

Comment: Can't you use `Hash::check('old_password', $user->password)`?

Answer (score 4):

I use this sollution for changing the password. In your rules you have one error: password_confirmation should be the same as password not password_confirmation.

Here is the complete and tested function:

```
public function changePassword($id){
    $rules = array(
        'old_password'                  => 'required',
        'new_password'                  => 'required|confirmed|different:old_password',
        'new_password_confirmation'     => 'required|different:old_password|same:new_password'
    );

    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    //Is the input valid? new_password confirmed and meets requirements
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        Session::flash('validationErrors', $validator->messages());
        return Redirect::back()->withInput();
    }

    //Is the old password correct?
    if(!Hash::check(Input::get('old_password'), $user->password)){
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withError('Password is not correct.');
    }

    //Set new password to user
    $user->password = Input::get('new_password');
    $user->password_confirmation = Input::get('new_password_confirmation');

    $user->touch();
    $save = $user->save();

    return Redirect::to('logout')->withMessage('Password has been changed.');

}
```

This also works if you dont work with Confide.

Answer (score 0):

From the github of confide:

Integrated with the Laravel Auth and Reminders component/configs.

So I would guess using the `Auth::validate()` method will do the trick.